# Cursor shows table has records but db file in DB Browser shows 0 tables in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My code shows table created in logcat successfully!
Also, shows `cursor.getCount()` to the `records` in `table` but when I `download` the `db file` from device explorer and open it in `db browser`, it shows 0 `table`.

The data and the tables are getting created successfully.But it seems that `db browser` doesn't show up the `table records` and the `tables` itself.

Logcat of Cursor
[image]

[image: db browser data]

**CODE: SQLITE DATABASE:**

```
package com.prajwal.restaurant.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class RestaurantDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Resto.db";
    public static SQLiteDatabase database;

    public static final String R_TABLE = "Restaurant_Data";
    public static final String _id = "_id";
    public static final String R_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String R_SEATS = "SEATS";
    public static final String R_CONTACT = "MOBILE_NO";
    public static final String R_AVAILABLE = "AVAILABLE_SEATS";
    public static final String R_LOGIN_EMAIL = "LOGIN_EMAIL";

    public static final String R_REVIEW = "Restaurant_Review";
    public static final String R_USERNAME = "Restaurant_USER";
    public static final String R_MARKS = "Restaurant_MARKS";

    public static final String CREATE_RESTAURANT_DATA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+R_TABLE+"(" +
            _id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            R_NAME + " TEXT," +
            R_SEATS + " INTEGER," +
            R_AVAILABLE + " INTEGER," +
            R_LOGIN_EMAIL + " TEXT," +
            R_CONTACT + " INTEGER);";

    public static final String CREATE_RESTAURANT_REVIEW = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+R_REVIEW+"(" +
            _id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            R_USERNAME + " TEXT," +
            R_MARKS + " TEXT);";


    public RestaurantDatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_RESTAURANT_DATA);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_RESTAURANT_REVIEW);
        Log.i("DATA","Table has been created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newversion) {
        switch (oldVersion) {
            case 1:
                //upgrade logic from version 1 to 2
            case 2:
                //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
                //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE R_TABLE ADD COLUMN R_AVAILABLE");
            case 3:
                //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
            case 4:
                //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
            case 5:
                //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
            case 6:
                //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3case 2:
                //                //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "onUpgrade() with unknown oldVersion " + oldVersion);
        }

    }

    public void delete(int anInt)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(R_TABLE,_id + "=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(anInt)});
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor getAll()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+R_TABLE,null);
        System.out.println(c);
        Log.d("DATA","CURSOR: "+c);
        return c;
    }
}
```

CODE: Insert

```
rowInserted = sqLiteDatabase.insert(R_TABLE, null, values);
```

Please help me to solve this issue!

Comment: Download also any Temporary Files Used By SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html

Comment: but for my other apps, the db browsers shows tables correctly

Comment: did but no use!

Comment: @forpas Thank you soo much brother!!! I was just downloading .db file!!!

Answer (score 0):

You also have to download other files like `.db-shm`, `db-wal` with `.db` file.

[image]

Comment: The same answer was mentioned by @forpas too in his comment. Pls avoid adding duplicate answers!

Comment: @PrajwalW, Probably you don't know the difference between *answer* and *comment*. Beside this I have mentioned here the exact temporary files specific to android. Hope you understand. Thanks